# Add <script> in wordpress post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor, tableofcontents, disable

I use the elementor plugin for the table of content, But I have a  code to minimize the table of content on the desktop.
I want to disable the table of content everywhere my site that I use it.

My code is:

```html
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
var delay = 100; setTimeout(function() { 
$('.elementor-widget-table-of-contents').addClass('elementor-toc--collapsed');
 $('.elementor-toc__body').css('display', 'none'); }, delay); 
}); 
</script>
```

How can I add this code correctly on my website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) to add your snippet to all the pages of your website. It supports PHP snippets, but you can just echo your script:

```
<?php
echo "<script> 
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
          var delay = 100; setTimeout(function() { 
              $('.elementor-widget-table-of-contents').addClass('elementor-toc--collapsed');
              $('.elementor-toc__body').css('display', 'none'); }, 
          delay); 
   }); 
   </script>"
;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your client-side solution (jQuery/Javascript + CSS) is not a good idea to remove TOC because your source code will be dirty and didn't change.

You must solve this problem with logical solutions like changing **Plugin's Settings** or using **PHP/Wordpress functions**.

Here is a better solution:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hide-or-remove-table-of-content/

Good Luck